# Can I make Eclipse underlines thicker?

Tags: eclipse

With a high resolution screen Eclipse editor's underlines are almost invisible even with contrast colors. Is there any way to make it thicker?
Is there any CSS or other setting that correlates to the thickness?

I'm using Mars.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in an easy way to change the thickness of the line.
The solution to make it more visible is to go to preferences -> annotations, select error and change the line property to a solid line, frame or boxed. This change makes the error visible enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the font type or the font size under Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts?